# Android String to int crashes my app

Tags: android, string, android-intent, int

I am trying to make an app where the user inputs a phone number into a `EditText` variable `NumberBox` which is than converted to int from string and used in the method `intent.putExtra("address", PhoneNumberint);` When I try to do this, the app just crashes, so please let me know what the problem is here. Is the conversion from string to int wrong in some way?

```
package com.example.module09;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //variables

    EditText    NumberBox;
    Button      SMSButton;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //

        NumberBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumberBox);
        SMSButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SMSButton); 
        final int PhoneNumberint = Integer.parseInt(NumberBox.getText().toString());


        //onclick
        SMSButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.putExtra("address", PhoneNumberint);
                intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use: `final int PhoneNumberint = Integer.valueOf(NumberBox.getText().toString());` instead.

Comment: Used this `Integer.valueOf(age.getText().toString());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try get value on onCreate method that is null, you must get value of that on button click like following code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //

        NumberBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumberBox);
        SMSButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SMSButton); 


        //onclick
        SMSButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                PhoneNumberint = Integer.parseInt(NumberBox.getText().toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.putExtra("address", PhoneNumberint);
                intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Ok I have moved the line into the onclick method and now the app works! However, the number that is inputted into the NumberBox variable does not appear in the SMS message. It just appears blank!

Comment: @ssj3goku878 Ask it as a separate question.

Comment: what you need exactly? put number to default sms application?

Comment: I would like the variable PhoneNumberint to be set as the number used for SMS. In this case, when I click the button SMSButton, the SMS number field is empty.

Comment: @ssj3goku878, do _not_ convert the String to an int. It's expecting the phone number (address) as a String.

Comment: see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463338/Sending-a-SMS-Message-from-an-Android-Application @ssj3goku878

Answer (score 4):

Just move this :

```
final int PhoneNumberint = Integer.parseInt(NumberBox.getText().toString());
```

from your `onCreate` method to the `onClick` method.

The app crashes because you have placed the above code in your `onCreate` method. Since at the time of `Activity` creation the value of `EditText` is **null** the `String` contains **null**. When `null` is parsed to `Integer` it throws an exception.

Comment: There is no need of final keyword while in `onClick()`

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform this on onCreate() method

```
 final int PhoneNumberint = Integer.parseInt(NumberBox.getText().toString());
```

At first time your String contains null data because it always be null values for your EditText and that's why you will be always get null pointer because you can't parse null value to int.

So better way it to move that line on Click event of Button.

Answer (score 1):

**The app crashes because of `NumberFormatException`**

The problem lies where you are extracting text from `EditText` before it is being set. If the content of EditText is empty/null string, `Integer.parseInt` will throw  `java.lang.NumberFormatException`
The culprit is this line:

```
final int PhoneNumberint = Integer.parseInt(NumberBox.getText().toString());
```

**To fix this**, `move this line under onClick()`. But the App will still crash, if the button is clicked without inputting anything in EditText.

**Before parsing the String to Int, write to check if the String is empty/null.**
On the lighter side, there is no need of `final` keyword here.